# How do you pass an array to an erb template in ruby and have it iterated over?

Tags: puppet, ruby, templates

I need some help with erb templates, I can't seem to get my head around passing an array and then iterating over it. 
My problem is this. 
I want to pass a few arrays:
`

```
device      => ["eth0", "br0"],
ipaddr      => ["192.168.12.166", "192.168.12.199"],
netmask     => ["255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0"], 
hwaddr      => '',
network     => '',
gateway     => ["192.168.12.254", "192.168.12.204"],
```

To a template that iterates over each item in the array and prints it out:

```
auto <%= device %> inet static                                                                                                                                        
address <%= ipaddr %>
netmask <%= netmask %>
broadcast <%= broadcast %>
gateway <%= gateway %>
```

As far as I can get so far is figuring out that I need to do something with `device.each |device| puts device`, but I don't know what the syntax is supposed to look like.
I believe you can tell what I'm trying to do from these snippets, and then you might understand that the entries need to be seperate, and not interpolated. 
Any help you can offer would be appreciated. I know I should be trying things out in irb and figuring them out from there, which is what I'm reading up on now.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a better fit over at Stack Overflow.

Comment: The moderators will do that; I've voted to close/move it there already.  Hopefully more will chime in.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

the basic syntax for using each in ruby is something like this:

```
array.each do |item_from_array| BLOCK
```

so if you only had one array then you could just do something like this:
(I would use a different name inside the vertical bars for clarity)

```
<% device.each do |dev| %>
  auto <%= dev %> inet static
<% end %>
```

However that would iterate over all of your devices first, before moving on to your ipaddr array. I'm guessing you want them each in turn auto, address, netmask, etc. In that case you'd be better off using a more 'traditional' index and looping through N times, like this:

```
<% for idx in (0..1) %>
  auto <%= device[idx] %> inet static
  address <%= address[idx] %>
  netmask <%= netmask[idx] %>
  broadcast <%= broadcast[idx] %>
<% end %>
```

Of course you need to think about what your maximum size of array is, and what to do if an array contains less entries than the others. You can find the maximum size of all the arrays by doing something like this: `[device,address,netmask,broadcast].map{|a| a.length}.max`

and you can skip over a particular array like this: `<% if idx < address.length %> address <%= address[idx] %><% end %>`

Comment: This works, and is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! There is a syntax error on the line `<% for idx in (0..1) $>` but I can't edit it unless I change 6 characters.

Comment: First example should be: `<% device.each do |dev| %> auto <%= dev %> inet static <% end %>`

Comment: @nocache this is pretty old, but thanks for including the ".each" example even though it didn't necessarily answer the OP question, it was what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

## ERB Templates for Dummies

Basic code:

```
require 'erb'
ERB.new(template).result binding_for_template
```

What are `template` and `binding_for_template`?

### Template

Just the template content. You can read it from a file just with a `File.read(path)`.

### Binding for template

A [binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Binding.html)

> encapsulate the execution context at some particular place in the code and retain this context for future use.

How do you use it? Easy:

```
def binding_for_my_template
  devices      = ["eth0", "br0"]
  ipaddrs      = ["192.168.12.166", "192.168.12.199"]
  netmasks     = ["255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.0"]
  hwaddrs      = ['']
  networks     = ['']
  gateways     = ["192.168.12.254", "192.168.12.204"]
  binding
end
```

That will return a binding with all six arrays (I changed `hwaddr` and `network` to arrays for consistency.

### Iterating over arrays

The usual way is using the `each` method, just like this:

```
<%- devices.each do |d| %>
  auto <%= d %> inet static
<%- end %>
```

but there are other methods if you wanna put all in one line, for example `devices.join ' '` will join all the strings with a space in between.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/templates.html). Quoting:

```
# Managed by Class['ntp']
<% servers_real.each do |server| -%>
server <%= server %>
<% end -%>

# ...
```

> This snippet will iterate over each entry in the array and print it
>   after a server statement, so, for example, the string generated from
>   the Debian template will end up with a block like this:

```
# Managed by Class['ntp']
server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Comment: This works if you're only using one variable, and the order doesn't matter. I'm trying to do something a little more complicated.